# PHP ActiveRecord batch delete inactivated account

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, batch-file, activation

my website using php activerecord to handle the sql
and there're three field inside the db:
joindate,status,activatecode

all registered member must activated in 24 hours,otherwise account will be deleted

how to write the php code to do this function?
the joindate now using php date('Y-m-d').
also the code can automatic work without manually launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get an accurate 24 hr deactivation, you will need to change the `joindate` sql field to type "datetime" which will also hold the time. Then use this code:

```
// In the following statement, $JoinDate holds the sql `joindate` field
$timeDiff = time() - strtotime($JoinDate);

if($timDiff/3600 > 24) {
    // code to be executed if it's past the 24 hrs period
}
```

Comment: how to made the function auto start?

Comment: By auto start you mean automatic execution? If so, PHP doesn't have any scheduling features. You can either run the script on every page load or use Cron which allows you to run scripts in time intervals.

Comment: my joindate is using php date('Y-m-d');